What logical differences did Ernst Schröder see between propositions and classes?
What are the differences, from the point of view of formal logic, that Ernst Schröder argued there were between genuine propositions and classes?
I understand that Schröder argues his views on the subject in Vorlesungen über die Algebra der Logik, but, apparently, his work, in German, has not been translated into English.
What academic references exist on this subject?

Maybe useful The Algebra of Logic tradition

In general, the post-Boole developement of Algebra of Logic exploited the dual interpretation, as calculus ofclasses and as calculus of propositions.

Schröder explained the difference to Peirce in a March 1897 letter (with reference to  Vorlesungen):"The very simple fact being: That every theorem\proposition holding good in the class-calculus also holds in the statement-calculus. But not vice versa." He proceeds to give examples which basically use that the Boolean algebra of statements is 2-valued (0,1) whereas for classes it is a general powerset with non-trivial subsets between empty and universal set.

@Conifold Superb. Thanks!
